# Windows Mobile 6.5 Silent Uninstall

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, cab

I would like to silently uninstall a Program that was installed from a CAB File with wceload.
This Program also appears in Remove Programs. Is there a way to uninstall with command line?

I have found this [Xml Configuration](http://www.soti.net/mc/help/Content/Manager/advxml.htm) but i dont understand how to execute this commands.
Is there a Program on Windows Mobile to run this XML Files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the uninstall wap provisiong xml you need to uninstall an application automatically on the link you provided.

You need:

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
<characteristic type="UnInstall">
    <characteristic type="Application 2">
      <parm name="uninstall" value="1" /> 
    </characteristic>
</characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg155034.aspx

to process such xml you need either a mobile management framework or use a simple app that uses DMProcessConfigXML. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158518.aspx. That means you need to write a little app that uses this API call.

On some devices (ie by Intermec) processing of xml is supported directly. For Intermec devices you just need to copy the xml to \Smartsystems\ConfigDir on the device.

From a PC you can use RAPIconfig to process such xml on a device using ActiveSync/WMDC. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737308.aspx.